# Not getting expected output...code is terminating unexpectedly (hackerank stack problem)

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic, output, terminate

I am struggling with this code. program is terminating unexpectedly. please help
problem link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximum-element/problem

```
10
1 97
2
1 20
2
1 26
1 20
2
3
1 91
```

if we input the above numbers in our program...it doesn't get to the end but stops executing midway
PLEASE HELP ME IN FINDING THE PROBLEM... is there a problem in dynamic allocation or any function...if you have time please visit problem link and help..thankyou

```
class stack
{
  public:
      int top = -1;
      int *s;
};

void create(stack *st,int n)
{
    st->s = new int[n];
}

void del(stack *st)
{
    st->top--;

}


void push(stack *st,int x)
{
    st->top++;
    st->s[st->top] = x;
    
}


int main()
{
    long int t;
    stack st;
    int choice;
    int number;
    int max =-1;
    
    cin>>t;
    
    create(&st,t);
    
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>choice;
        
        if(choice == 1)
        {
            cin>>number;
            push(&st,number);
            if(max < number)
                max = number;
        }
        else if(choice == 2)
        {
            del(&st);
        }
        else
        {
           return max;
        }
        
    }
    
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please re-read the instructions, and check what you do on `3`.

Comment: I am really for that...actually this is my first question here..that's why

Comment: Never underestimate the power of the debugger.

Comment: It's cool, but please stay away from ALL CAPS.

Comment: Yep, you can always [edit] your question and write it in normal case. And if you do so, you might as well add a summary of the task to make your question self contained. To address your code: I think you need to update `max` when removing an element from the stack too, not just when adding.

Comment: yes, sir..thanks for helping. I will keep that in mind from next time

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: Why is there a `create` function when in C++ you'd implement a proper constructor for that `struct`? Don't treat C++ as "fancy C". Use it properly and your life will be way easier.

Comment: Thinking about it, you might want to store not the actual number, but `max`on the stack and for case 3 you want to print the top element of the stack instead of `max`.

Comment: sir problem is that my code is not even taking input till last...it gets terminate midway.

Comment: Probably because of `return max` in case 3. You are supposed to print the value, not return it.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the mentioned problem in much shorter and clean code if you use C++ containers and algorithms.

[Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/itD4T9MWARv7zQZy) is some self-explanatory code :

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// driver function
int main() {

    // fast I/O
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);

    int n, i = 0, q;
    std::cin >> n;

    // make a vector of n elements, here I have took size n because we have
    // total n queries and in worst case all of them can be of type 1, which
    // makes the maximum possible size to n
    std::vector<int> v(n);

        // iterate n times to read all queries
        while (n--) {

        // input query type
        std::cin >> q;

        // query type 1
        if (q == 1)
            // increment the top index (i) and insert value to top
            std::cin >> v[++i];

        // query type 2
        else if (q == 2)
            // decrement top, logically it is similar to removing top element
            // if we always consider vector from zeroth to top index
            --i;

        // query type 3
        else if (q == 3)
            // here I am using max_element function from standard algorithms
            // library
            std::cout << *std::max_element(v.begin(), v.begin() + i + 1)
                      << '\n';
    }
}
```

---

**Edit :** [This implementation](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jlVy7zMjv3pOL9RP) has lesser complexity, it will work without fast I/O. [*v2 here.*](https://wandbox.org/permlink/o9EUEF5kvEQYFKUT) Check [discussion section](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximum-element/forum) for better (`O(1)` time complexity) implementations.

Comment: I upvote for good coding style and use of stl-methods and it technically solves OP's problem :D Allthough I suspect this will cause TLE sooner or later, because case 3 has linear time complexity.